Why does not all uranium undergo fission in a nuclear bomb explosion?
As per this article, The weight of a butterfly,

Of the 64 kilograms of uranium in the bomb, less than one kilogram underwent fission

Why does not all uranium undergo fission in a nuclear explosion?

At the instant the bomb goes off, it starts expanding very quickly, and equally quickly the density of (expanding) uranium falls below the critical density required to entrap neutrons and thereby sustain a chain reaction. At the point where this happens, very little of the original charge of uranium has had a chance to fission.

The amount of U-235 which was consumed in the fission in that bomb is estimated to be one kilogram out of 64 kg total.
"  Of the 64 kilograms of uranium in the bomb, less than one kilogram underwent fission, and the entire energy of the explosion came from just over half a gram of matter that was converted to energy. That is about the weight of a butterfly." quoted from the article!
That one kilogram is converted to other elements. total weight of those elements after the fission is estimated to be barely (0.5 milligrams) less than the initial one kilogram. That, butterfly mass, was converted to energy!
The rest of U-235 was vaporized in the great heat and pressure of the nuclear explosion!

The reaction is only self sustaining if enough neutrons trigger fission to repopulate the place with more neutrons. The bombs are stored at a critical mass of below 0.9. In order to get a respectable yield, you want to get to at least 3 critical masses in about 3 microseconds, and then shower the pit in neutrons. The way you get the same material to suddenly be three times the critical mass is to compress it by about 50%. That will drive the propagation factor (k) to about 2 - the number of neutrons double each generation. The reaction will ramp up from there as long as k remains greater than 1, then the reactions fade quickly, and we just have fallout. Modern bombs have a burnup of about 25%, and some stupid big ones in the past got to nearly 50% burnup. But the one you are asking about was a gun type weapon, and you just can't assemble the pieces fast enough to drive the k factor to 2 and keep it there.
So your question amounts to why does the critical mass go down as density squared. Why do we go from k<0.9 to k=2ish just by compressing it to 1/2 its original volume?
The answer is that the fraction of neutrons that escape the core - the cross section of escape - is very sensitive to density. The mean free path of a neutron gets larger by one over density squared. But the diameter of the sphere goes as density ^-1/3. So in an expanding sphere, the mean free path gets bigger much faster than the sphere of material gets bigger. That means more neutrons leak out of the less dense sphere and the k factor falls off until it is below 1.
